# How to load text from a form field on another page?

Tags: jquery

My actual code is this:

`link = $('a[href*="cadernoedit"]').attr('href');` //stores the link

`$('body').append('<div id="result"></div>');` //places a div to insert the result

`text = $('#result').load(link_sinopse + ' #x_caderno_texto');` //insert the result

But the result is a complete field (with a field box). 
How is the code the get only text from a form field from another page?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $('<div></div>');
result.load(link_sinopse + ' #x_caderno_texto', 
    function() {
        var text = result.find("#idOfTheField").val();
    }
);
```

Comment: `load()` is asynchronous. Your `find()` will fire before request completes

Comment: You are right, I added a callback to the `load()` function.